# Java Client for HighChart Export server REST service

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, highcharts

I have been trying to create a small java client to call Highchart Export server to get the pdf/jpeg etc.. but it is not successful using Spring's RestTemplate -> RestTemplate restTemplate = new org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate() in the client side. I tried post/get/exchange methods.. but unable to PASS the required method parameters to the server side... the required method is getting called without the params and returnd their test jsp page.

Highchart Export Server code =>

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ExportController extends HttpServlet {
...
...
    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public HttpEntity<byte[]> exporter(
        @RequestParam(value = "svg", required = false) String svg,
        @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String type,
        @RequestParam(value = "filename", required = false) String filename,
        @RequestParam(value = "width", required = false) String width,
        @RequestParam(value = "scale", required = false) String scale,
        @RequestParam(value = "options", required = false) String options,
        @RequestParam(value = "globaloptions", required = false) String globalOptions,
        @RequestParam(value = "constr", required = false) String constructor,
        @RequestParam(value = "callback", required = false) String callback,
        @RequestParam(value = "callbackHC", required = false) String callbackHC,
        @RequestParam(value = "async", required = false, defaultValue = "false")  Boolean async,
        @RequestParam(value = "jsonp", required = false, defaultValue = "false") Boolean jsonp,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session) throws ServletException, InterruptedException, SVGConverterException, NoSuchElementException, PoolException, TimeoutException, IOException, ZeroRequestParameterException {
...
}

}
```

What method in RestTemplate should I call and how to pass the params from client side like JSON formatted options, type etc, so that above Service method gets executed with proper params? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work after passing values in org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap object like

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> prms = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(); 
prms.add("param1", "value1"); 
prms.add("param2", "value2");
```

and then calling..

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
byte[] b = restTemplate.postForObject("http://****/", prms, byte[].class);
```